# Internationalising in embedded javascript files

Tags: javascript, symfony, internationalization, translation, webpack-encore

I've been playing with symfony and it's many features. After deciding to get the internationalisation stuff out of the way, I found a relatively new article in the docs about translation [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html).
So, using twig I can do things like

```
<label>{% trans %}What needs translating{% endtrans %}
```

Pretty clean and straightforward, but now I need to be able to do that in javascript files that I import in the page header.

```
<script src="{{ asset('build/myjs.js') }}"></script>

// myjs.js
const test = {% trans %}What needs translating{% endtrans %};
```

Is there something similar to [FOSJsRoutingBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle) (a bundle that enables generating routes in javascript, e.g `Routing.generatePath('home')`)

I use [Webpack Encore](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend.html) to bundle all my javascript and CSS files, maybe some kind of injection is possible?